# Wordpress social icons not linking to social media account?

Tags: wordpress, links, social-media

I'm new to WP so maybe I'm looking at the wrong place but-

I have social icons at the top of my website (as is default by the WP Theme). I want the icons (FB, Twitter, YT, Linkedin, Skype) to link to my accounts.

On the backend I went to

```
 appearance >>> 
 Theme options >>>
 Social media
```

Here I found the option to add the links to my social media. In lieu of the links being there were pound (#) signs. When you click on the social media links right now it goes to the URL mywebsite.com/#.

I added all of the social links facebook.com/facebookPage, Twitter.com/twitterpage, etc. After saving and testing the links I'm still ending up on mywebsite.com/# and not on my social media pages.

I then tried on leaving the page info instead of the full link so instead of facebook.com/facebookpage I would have "facebookPage" in case WP adds the facebook.com itself.

Again, same result. Mywebsite.com/#.

The social icons are on both the Header and Footer of the theme and it's the Avada theme.

Comment: This sounds like a question pertaining to the Wordpress theme you're using and not Wordpress in general. You may need to ask this question directly to the theme developer.